# On PowerApps, every time I save a new item, the item on the form switches to the first item on the Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

On PowerApps, every time I save a new item, the item on the form switches to the first item on the Sharepoint list

If I run SubmitForm on the onSelect of a button, the item switches to the first item on the list, and a Flow is running with the ID of the first item on the list, rather than the new created item.

The button OnSelect is the following:

```
SubmitForm(SharePointForm1);Set(varKickNotified,true);'Kick-Off_Notify_V2'.Run(DataCardValue41)
```

The idea is to save the record, set a variable saying that the action has started, and starts a flow with DataCardValue41 being the List item ID.

The OnSuccess is the following:

```
Refresh(Moving_articles);Set(LastAddedItemID,First(Sort(Moving_articles,ID,SortOrder.Descending)).ID)
```

The LastAddedItemID was an attempt to obtain the ID of new item to run the Flow with, but with no results.

The Item in SharePointForm1 is the following:

```
If(IsBlank(SharePointIntegration.Selected) || IsEmpty(SharePointIntegration.Selected),First(Sort(Moving_articles,ID,SortOrder.Descending)),SharePointIntegration.Selected)
```

Also here, an attempt to get the last added item by the first and sort functions.

Apparently, the problem is that when the new record is created, the selected item is the first item of the list, so the Flow isn't running with the ID of the new created record, but with data from the first item of the list, which is a very strange behaviour.

What I want the app to do is:

The user clicks on New in Sharepoint, which opens the form
The user fills the form
Then it clicks on a 'Notify Team' button, which saves the record, and triggers a flow that will send a whole bunch of e-mails with the information contained in the new created list item.

In my humble poweruser (not programmer) opinion, it seems something that should be as default in PowerApps, but it's getting very hard to get. I already made a mess with commented code and variable set functions just attempting to make this work. I'm stuck on it for almost a week.

Could you give me any assistance on this?